# Install boot loader with no operating system on hard drive

Tags: windows, linux, boot, bootloader

I am trying to reset — or rather, install — a boot loader on my hard drive. I initially had a Linux distro installed, which I completely wiped out. Now, when I try to install Windows 7 from my USB, my machine says

> Missing operating System

And when I don't boot with USB, it says

> "bootmgr is missing"

So now I am wondering, how I can install a boot loader, so I can install Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

Do you still have your original windows disc?

If not [download one](http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65805/X15-65805.iso). Either boot from it or copy it to a pendrive and boot from the pendrive. 
(You can use [this tool from microsoft](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) to move the ISO files to a pendrive).

Do **not** select "Install now". Instead use the "Repair your computer" option.

[image]

Now either use "startup repair", or use "Command prompt" and type `bootrec /fixboot'

[image]

Done.